# What is the performance issue in this file conversion code?

Tags: c#, file, optimization, hex

I am attempting to create a tool that converts files from an xbox format to a format useable in the pc version of the engine however in order to do this I must make the hex in the file little endian and preserve the strings.

I have attempted to debug the code and I believe that the bottleneck may be in the 'ReadHex' function, specifically when appending to the string 'hex'.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the directory containing files: ");
        var path = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string hex = ReadHex(file);
            var x = FindHexStrings(hex);
            var removed = x.Item1;
            var positions = x.Item2;

            for (int i = 0; i < removed.Count; i++)
            {
                hex = hex.Remove(positions[i], removed[i].Length);
            }

            hex = ChunkIntoFourBytes(hex);

            for (int i = 0; i < removed.Count; i++)
            {
                hex = hex.Insert(positions[i], removed[i]);
            }

            var stream = new FileStream( Path.GetFileName(file) , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            WriteHexStringToFile(hex, stream);

            stream.Close();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void WriteHexStringToFile(string hexString, FileStream stream)
    {
        var twoCharacterBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        var oneByte = new byte[1];
        foreach (var character in hexString.Where(c => c != ' '))
        {
            twoCharacterBuffer.Append(character);

            if (twoCharacterBuffer.Length == 2)
            {
                oneByte[0] = Convert.ToByte(twoCharacterBuffer.ToString(), 16);
                stream.Write(oneByte, 0, 1);
                twoCharacterBuffer.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    static string LittleEndian(string num)
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(num, 16);
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
        string retval = "";
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
            retval += b.ToString("X2");
        return retval;
    }

    public static void ConvertHexToAscii(string hexString)
    {
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string hs = string.Empty;

            hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
            uint decval = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
            char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
            ascii += character;

        }

        Console.WriteLine(ascii);
    }

    static Tuple<List<string>, List<int>> FindHexStrings(string str)
    {
        int position=-1;
        string hexstring="";

        List<string> removed = new List<string>();
        List<int> positions = new List<int>();

        int chunkSize = 2;
        int stringLength = str.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
        {
            if (i + chunkSize > stringLength) chunkSize = stringLength - i;
            if (int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) >= 0x30 && int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) <= 0x39 || int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) >= 0x41 && int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) <= 0x5A || int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) >= 0x61 && int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) <= 0x7A || int.Parse(str.Substring(i, chunkSize), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) == 0x5F) //Is valid hex character for ascii sequence
            {
                if (hexstring.Length == 0) { position = i; }

                hexstring += str.Substring(i, chunkSize);
            }
            else
            {
                if (hexstring.Length >= 8) { removed.Add(hexstring); positions.Add(position); }

                position = -1;
                hexstring = "";
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Removed strings:");
        removed.ForEach(ConvertHexToAscii);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPositions:");
        positions.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        return new Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>(removed, positions);
    }

    static string ChunkIntoFourBytes(string str)
    {
        string final = "";

        int chunkSize = 8;
        int stringLength = str.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
        {
            if (i + chunkSize > stringLength) chunkSize = stringLength - i;
            final+=LittleEndian(str.Substring(i, chunkSize));
        }

        return final;
    }

    static string ReadHex(string directory)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(directory, FileMode.Open);
        int hexIn;
        string hex = "";

        for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++)
        {
            hex += string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
        }

        return hex;
    }

}
```

I expected handling larger files to take only a small amount longer than small files however it seems to take multiple hours or not even process at all since none of the larger files have been processed, unlike the smaller ones.

Comment: Why are you converting from binary and the swapping and writing back as binary.  First you should be using BinaryReader and BinaryWriter.  Then do the conversion in binary.  If you are swapping 4 bytes then read uint32, do the Big/Little Endian swap, then write the results.  It is like 10 lines of code instead of the mess you wrote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, appending to a string is a major bottleneck. A string is immutable like a `struct` so every time you append to it you are actually re-creating a brand new object.

What you want to use is a `StringBuilder` object. The `StringBuilder` is made for appending string together. Once you are done you simple call the `var mystring = stringBuilderObject.ToString();`

You can see the full `StringBuilder` documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Oh I assumed it was in the hex conversion if anything, I'll go try using stringbuilder now and come back with the results. Thanks!

Edit: It worked perfectly and the performance is fixed, thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is very simple code.  Not sure I got the byte swapping correct, but it easy to change.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the directory containing files: ");
            var path = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            byte[] temp = new byte[4];
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Count(); i += 4)
                {
                    temp[0] = buffer[i + 3];
                    temp[1] = buffer[i + 2];
                    temp[2] = buffer[i + 1];
                    temp[3] = buffer[i];

                    Array.Copy(temp, 0, buffer, i, 4);

                }
                File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```